# Getting "Dereferencing null/undefined value." while trying to fill array in the loop in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, makecode

I'm quite new to TypeScript and this is one of my first projects in Microsoft Makecode Arcade. Trying to fill an array as a class property using loop.

```
class Game {
    grid: number[][]

    constructor() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            let row: number[] = []
            for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                row.push(0)
                console.log(row)
            }
            this.grid.push(row)
        }
    }
}
```

Getting an error "Dereferencing null/undefined value", however, `console.log(row)` shows the correct array `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: you define `grid` as the first thing in your class and give it a type, but it has no initialized value.  The default value here is `undefined` which is probably why you are getting an error.  Either assign a value for it where you create that property, or inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't initialize `grid` ([demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiYFsCm0DeBYAUNH0DmATgJYAmAXNAHYCuCARkgQNoC6rWWu0wA9pRABcC1YAJ4EAFAEo0nLrgEALIhAB0hUtAC80dtnk4AZuOgSQSAdCLboABgDcV6AB5oAJgdWA1F5kZ9BlzmlgQ8AO4UNPSMrDZ6gfLGBKbB0ABWNp4ZrgCMWT5+cgkGoWGqAA7UEIoStlJFxQC+DQlKKurEJBVVNaX1AfLNA0NDWLz8lng2lEhhcIhI0mN8EDzmqiA8eBJ4HaRSQA))

```
class Game {
    grid: number[][]

    constructor() {
        this.grid = []
        for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            let row: number[] = []
            for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                row.push(0)
            }
            this.grid.push(row)
        }
    }
}
```